# Snap packages not working on ubuntu 22.04 with wayland

Tags: nvidia, uefi, snap, secure-boot, snap-store

I switched to using ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland, I noticed that some snap packages don't work.

Between them: Firefox, Insomnia e Beekeeper Studio

I'm using a clean install of Ubuntu.

Nvidia: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3GB Max-Q]

Secure boot: enabled

UEFI: enabled

Ubuntu with X11 works great.

Comment: I only have this data at the moment, I also use of course Nvidia, active securet boot and EFI.

The installation of my Ubuntu is clean, I did not update.

Comment: Add the info of your graphics card to the question. It is important. nvidia support for Wayland is brand new, so there would be no surprise if there remain issues with some cards. You probably will better stick with Xorg for the coming period. b.t.w., Snap firefox runs on Xwayland. The others perhaps also, and the issue may be there.